# XML Layout weight not working in a ScrollView on android API23

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I am doing an Android project in AndroidStudio where a ScrollView contains a vertical LinearLayout and within that LinearLayout there is an ImageView and another LinearLayout. I am trying to set the ImageView to be 10 times smaller than the LinearLayout, the result is showing up correct in the Preview window but not on my phone (Xperia Z3 with API23).

[This is what I see in the preview window and what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGsNT.png)

But on my phone the image fills the width of the screen and the image height is proportional to the original image(almost fills half the screen, so far from what it should be according to the weights)

The app worked like it is supposed to on a Google Pixel 7.1.1 with API25.

Here is a part of the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/bjj2" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <LinearLayout
                ...rest of the app
         </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the full code https://github.com/IvarsGoldingen/Bjjscorekeeper/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should understand how dimensions are calculated.
Let's look one by one.

1) `ScrollView` is `fill_parent`/`fill_parent` (actually one can change this to `match_parent`/`match_parent` as `fill_parent` is deprecated as far as I remember, but it doesn't matter in this case).
So, `ScrollView` is shown fits whole screen (width and height).

2) `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView` is `match_parent`/`wrap_content`. And that is correct. One should use `wrap_content` for views that inside `ScrollView`.
The reason why - is that `ScrollView` is used to wrap **long** views with usually unknown height (like lists). Imagine here `match_parent` as height - height of `LinearLayout` would be calculated based on height of scroll view, which is whole screen height, and `LinearLayout` height can be greater that screen height. Just not logical. But everything is OK till now. Move on.

3) Items inside `LinearLayout`. You want them to be `1/10` and `9/10` of height of parent layout. Also, you set `height` for inner items to `0` to show that you want height to be calculated from `weights`.
And here you got a **cycle** of dependencies. `LinearLayout` height is `wrap_content` and depends on sum of heights of inner elements.
And inner elements' height is calculated from parent `LinearLayout` height.

Additionally, you want `ImageView` to be 1/10 of the `LinearLayout` height. But actually seems like you want `ImageView` to be `1/10` of the **screen's** height, as `LinearLayout` height can be greater than screen's height (and looks like this is what you get on your device).

You say, that everything is OK in preview in Android Studio.
To demonstrate that not everything is OK try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/bjj2" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Just put some big (bigger than screen's height) view inside your inner-inner `LinearLayout` and you will see that in preview your image is bigger than `1/10` of screen's height. But it is `1/10` of `LinearLayout`'s height.

How to solve your issue?
I think the only way is to calculate `1/10` of the screen's height and resize bitmap with image you want to have and set that bitmap to `ImageView`.
Or any other way to set exact height to `ImageView`.

Or review your layout and create something different.

Comment: I do want the image to be 1/10 of the LinearLayout's, not the screen - not necessary as the final app, but just as an example that it is not working on my phone. I experimented with your code and the problem only exists if the height of the inner item exceeds the screen height(the app becomes scrollable).
Here I set the height of the view 200dp and the Image is 1/10 of the Layout:
http://i.imgur.com/YHZvFMO.png
And here the View is 400dp, as you can see the image fills the width of the screen and is not 1/10 of the Layout:
http://i.imgur.com/HP4cPUH.png
http://i.imgur.com/9ybTt3z.png

Comment: I see the dependencies problem in my code. Please tell me if I am understanding this correctly: "I should not use layout_weight and wrap_content on a LinearLayout together, because they will depend on each other". But it is kind of weird that the problem only occurs when scrollview becomes scrollable(the inner elements exceed the screens height).

Answer (score 0):

we can set height of the image view at run time by avoiding layout_weight using display metrics .

e.g

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            yourImageView.getLayoutParams().height = height / 5;
            yourImageView.getLayoutParams().width = width / 4;
```